# Polarized Microwaves Proportional to |Cosine| instead of Cosine Squared?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

My college physics class did a lab on the Law of Malus today using a microwave generator and receiver with a polarizing plate in between, after completing the lab I noticed that my data seemed to suggest that the intensity of the wave was proportional to the absolute value of the cosine of the angle difference between the generator and the receiver where I<sub>o</sub> is the intensity when the receiver and generator are in the same rotated orientation, that is I = I<sub>o</sub>*|Cos(θ)|, or I<sup>2</sup> = (I<sub>o</sub>Cos(θ))<sup>2</sup>
instead of being proportional to the square of the cosine of the angles between them.

Is there a reason this might have occurred? I haven't been able to track down anything that suggests the intensity of the wave might be proportional to anything other than the square of the cosine.

Note: I am currently talking with my professor about why it might be and considering the possible failures of the equipment used in the lab.

Edit: Apparently this detector's (Pasco WA-9800A) meter reading is not directly proportional to either the intensity or electric field of the microwave that it is detecting. Though it claims to be useful for measuring relative intensities which was the purpose of the lab.

Comment: What exactly did you measure? Amplitude of the electric field?

Comment: @Pieter I believe we measured the intensity of the electric field, which is proportional to the square of the amplitude of the electric field.

Comment: What exactly did you measure? What kind of instrument or detector?

Comment: We were measuring current in mA with a small galvanometer attached to the detector, I'm not sure exactly what kind of detector we were using.

Comment: Finally determined what kind of detector we were using, it was a Pasco WA-9800A, which according to the assembly/use documentation provided by Pasco reads out somewhere between the intensity and the magnitude of the electric field instead of one or the other.

[Documentation link](ftp://ftp.pasco.com/Support/Documents/English/WA/WA-9314C/Bsc%20Microwave%20Optic%20Mnl%20(%20WA-9314C)%20.pdf)

Comment: Ah, Pasco writes: "This non-linearity will provide no problem in most experiments." But it is a problem when trying to do a quantitative test of Malus' Law. I suppose your professor may have known that, nice opportunity for a learning experience  :)

Comment: But is that non-linearity an issue when we were measuring the relative strengths of the field at various points? They claim their apparatus will work for it and include a description of a lab to verify Malus' Law in another document they distribute with the sets that the receiver is also sold in.

Comment: I looked at their experiment guide [link](https://www.pasco.com/file_downloads/Downloads_Manuals/Microwave-Optics-Experiment-Guide-WA-9314C.pdf). Experiment 5 is about polarization. In Question 2, there is quite a big if: "If the Receiver’s meter reading was directly proportional to the incident microwave’s intensity", then one would measure Malus' law. It probably depends on the power level at which the system is operating how strong the nonlinearities are.

Comment: Ah, thanks for noticing that. I somehow managed to overlook it. If you write that into an answer I'll gladly it mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that I arrived at with the poster's help. Pasco's [experiment guide](https://www.pasco.com/file_downloads/Downloads_Manuals/Microwave-Optics-Experiment-Guide-WA-9314C.pdf) mentions non-linearities in their detector. Experiment 5 is about polarization. In Question 2, there is quite a big **if**: "If the Receiver’s meter reading was directly proportional to the incident microwave’s intensity", then one would measure Malus' law. It probably depends on the power level at which the system is operating how strong the nonlinearities are.